# Output a variable as string through passing function

Tags: c++, string, pointers

```
1 void out3x3(mat3x3 &A)
2 { int i, j;
3   for (i=0; i<3; i++)
4   {   if (i==1)
5           cout << "A = | ";
6       else
7           cout << "    | ";
8       for (j=0; j<3; j++)
9           cout << A.n[j][i] << " ";
10      cout << "|" << endl;
11   }
12 }
```

This is a function in a program I'm writing to do matrix manipulations.  mat3x3 is a structure for a 3x3 matrix (stored as A.n[3][3]. Instead of 'A' in the output in line 5, I'd like it to output the name of whatever variable I used for the matrix in the calling function.

I only use A, B, and C.  I could just write three different functions, but I feel like there should be a better way to do it.

If I say out3x3(B); it will only show A = | |.

I would like this to happen:

out3x3(B);

```
B = | |
```

out3x3(C);

```
C = | |
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can pass name as first argument `std::string const & name` and print it instead of `A`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Names of variables do not exist at run time. They are simply compile time constructs. You would need to do something like change the function to take a `std::string` argument too:

```
void out3x3(mat3x3 &A, std::string name)
{
  // ...
  cout << name << " = | ";
  // ...
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
out3x3(A, "A");
out3x3(B, "B");
```

You could then use a macro to make this *feel* like you're not duplicating the variable name. However, I don't recommend this at all. Instead, I recommend just making your function print out the contents of the matrix (between the `|`s) and then doing this:

```
cout << "A = ";
out3x3(A);
```

The printing of the variable name should be entirely independent of printing out the contents of the matrix. Consider the following analogy:

```
int x = 5;
cout << x;
```

This just prints out the value of `x`, nothing else. If I want to label it, I have to do that manually:

```
int x = 5;
cout << "x = " << x;
```

And who knows? Maybe you'll get round to overloading `operator<<` for your `mat3x3` type and soon you'll be doing this:

```
cout << "A = " << A;
```

Much prettier.

Comment: This, plus a `#define matrixOut(matrixName) out3x3( matrixName, #matrixName )` or the like...

Comment: @cHao My recommendation is that they avoid doing that.

Comment: The problem with printing the name separately is that the formatting will be messed up if the variable name is more than one letter.

Comment: @cHao Well I also recommend not making the output dependent on starting at the right position in the line. :D

Comment: If only we could just up and change the problem like that.  :)

Comment: How can I force my output to align?  cHao raises the same issue I have with this approach.  Please advise :)

Perhaps I could just manually insert the number of indents before each line, like out3x3(A, 7) and then I could output A^-1 = | | with 7 offset spaces for the other rows.

Comment: @Michael The very simple approach is to place a new line after `A = `. This is how, for example, Matlab prints its output.

Comment: hmm, I guess I'll end my quest for the zero G pen.  Thanks very much for the help everyone!

Comment: just an update, I took your recommendation (especially after affirming what you said about matlab which I somehow never noticed).  It looks great!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a macro as a wrapper to call it

```
#define OUT3X3(mat)        \
    out3x3(&mat, ##mat);
```

and change the function prototype to

```
void out3x3(mat3x3 &A, string name)
```

The call would be

```
OUT3X3(A);
```